# In wxPython, how is the wx.App object informed about the widgets it includes

Tags: wxpython

I was reading a wxPython tutorial and was confused by the initial example. Specifically, how does the wx.App object know anything about MyFrame object (which inherits from wx.Frame) in this code:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='Hello World')
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos=(5, 5))
        my_btn = wx.Button(panel, label='Press Me', pos=(5, 55))

        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I'd understand if MyFrame were somehow passed to app (or vice-versa), but that doesn't happen. How do these two objects know of each other's existence?

Comment: wxPython is looking for a frame. The loop picks ups the frame, (in this case MyFrame, ( based on wx.Frame)) and displays it

Comment: @Psionman - But how does the loop (app) know where to look for the frame? Does wxPython have each frame recorded in some central ledger with all relevant metadata?

Comment: Think of it this way: it's waits for a TopLevelWindow,  a frame or dialog, if one isn't explicitly set, it will use the first one you define. The program will terminate when that window is destroyed.